# Flushright square mark

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, symbols

I write the codes below to get a square as if to say q.e.d.

```
$$equation$$\textbox{\hfill\square}

Text\textbox{\hfill\square}
```

I want the square at the right extreme of the same line. I succeed only when the rest of the line has text and/or an equation within $ $, but not when it has an equation within $$ $$. In this case the square appears in the extreme right but in the next line but I want it on the same line.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You probably want `\qedhere` of `amsthm`; this requires using `\[...\]` rather than `$$...$$` (which shouldn't be used in LaTeX anyway).

Comment: Is this use of the qed symbol supposed to happen in conjunction with `proof` environments, or more generally?

Comment: Related Question: [Bump right-aligned text to next line iff no room](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91548/bump-right-aligned-text-to-next-line-iff-no-room).

Answer (score 6):

Use `amsthm` and its `proof` environment. If a proof ends with a displayed equation, `itemize` or `enumerate`, use `\qedhere` in the last line.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
This proof ends with a displayed equation
\[
1+1=2.\qedhere
\]
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
This proof ends normally,
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Never* use `$$...$$` in LaTeX, see [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

Answer (score 2):

You can load the `ntheorem` package with the `thmmarks` and `amsmath` options. Normally it can manage any display math environment, including the amsmath ones. Of course, it is incompatible with loading the `amsthm` package, but some compatibility is ensured by the `amsthm` option, which defines a proof environment and  plain, definition and remark theorem styles similar to the `amsthm` ones.

The `\qed` command ensures an *automatic* placement of the qed symbol, which can be redefined through the `\qedsymbol` command. In case of a problem within a single theoremlike environment, you can inactivate the automatic placement with the `\NoEndMark` command and proceed to a manual placement. See § 2.6 of the doc for details.

By the way, you shouldn't use `$$ ... $$` for displayed equations: it is pure TeX, and the vertical spacing can be incorrect. You should use `\[ ... \]` instead.

Here is an example with an align* environment, that demonstrates that no manual placement is necessary:

```
       \documentclass{article}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage{mathtools}
        \usepackage[amsthm,  thmmarks,amsmath]{ntheorem}

        \begin{document}

        \begin{proof}
        This proof ends with two displayed equations:
        \begin{align*}
        1 + 1  &  =  2\\
        2+2 & =4.
        \end{align*}
        \end{proof}

        \begin{proof}
        This proof ends normally,
        \end{proof}

        \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What purpose does redefining `\qed` as `\qedsymbol` serve?

Comment: Customising the endmark of a theorem-like environment. `\qed` is defined per environment. It prints the value of `\qedsymbol` for the current environment and globally, it is empty. For the standard configuration (option `standard`), it is defined as `\blacksquare`for proof environments. Otherwise it's up to you to define which environments require an "endmark", and you may decide different endmarks for different environments.

Comment: Added an example to show the capabilities of `ntheorem`.