# Bump right-aligned text to next line iff no room within a \savebox

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, boxes

This is a follow up to my earlier question [Bump right-aligned text to next line iff no room](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91548/bump-right-aligned-text-to-next-line-iff-no-room).  The difference now is that I need to place this formatted text within a `\savebox`. In my actual use case, for performance reasons, I am caching the text that needs to follow existing text (i.e., on the same line), and this cached text contains some text that is to be right aligned to the edge of the page.

I attempted to use all four solutions at [Bump right-aligned text to next line iff no room](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91548/bump-right-aligned-text-to-next-line-iff-no-room) along with a simple `\hfill`. These all seems to work when used outside of the `\savebox`, but not when inside the `\savebox`:

[image]

### Notes:

- I can *not* use `\parbox{\linewidth}{}` as I don't know where on the line the `\savebox` will start.  That is, there is text on the same line *before* the `\usebox` is applied.
- The desired version would have the `XXX` aligned on the right as is the `ZZZ` text.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newsavebox{\MyCachedResults}

% The following are from
%    https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91548/bump-right-aligned-text-to-next-line-iff-no-room

\newcommand*{\BumpCarlisle}[1]{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91556/4301
    {\rightskip\fill\parfillskip-\rightskip
    \linepenalty100
    \exhyphenpenalty0
    \linebreak[0] % <-- Need space here
    %Space before \hspace* allows for a break before it
    \hspace*{\fill}#1}%
}

\newcommand*{\FillLineEgreg}[1]{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91564/4301
    {%
        \nobreak\hfill\penalty50\hskip1em\null\nobreak
        \hfill#1%
        \parfillskip=0pt \finalhyphendemerits=0 \par%
     }%
}


\newcommand{\signed}[1]{%https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91563/4301
    {%
        \leavevmode\unskip\nobreak\hfil\penalty50\hskip2em
        \hbox{}\nobreak\hfil#1%
        \parfillskip=0pt \finalhyphendemerits=0 \endgraf%
    }%
}

\newcommand*{\FillLineTohecz}[1]{%
    \raggedright
    \parfillskip-\rightskip
    \looseness=-1 % <-- Need space here
    %Space before \hspace* allows for a break before it
    \hspace*{0pt plus 1fil}%
    #1% 
}
  
\begin{document}

\bigskip\noindent
\savebox{\MyCachedResults}{Inside Savebox Carlisle: \BumpCarlisle{XXX}}%
Outside Savebox Carlisle: \BumpCarlisle{ZZZ}\par
\noindent
Text \usebox{\MyCachedResults}%

\bigskip\noindent
\savebox{\MyCachedResults}{Inside Savebox egreg: \FillLineEgreg{XXX}}%
Outside Savebox egreg: \FillLineEgreg{ZZZ}\par
\noindent
Some Text \usebox{\MyCachedResults}%

\bigskip\noindent
\savebox{\MyCachedResults}{Inside Savebox Seamus: \signed{XXX}}%
Outside Savebox Seamus: \signed{ZZZ}\par
\noindent
A bit of text \usebox{\MyCachedResults}%

\bigskip\noindent
\savebox{\MyCachedResults}{Inside Savebox tohecz: \FillLineTohecz{XXX}}%
Outside Savebox tohecz: \FillLineTohecz{ZZZ}\par
\noindent
Text before the bump \usebox{\MyCachedResults}%


\bigskip\noindent
\savebox{\MyCachedResults}{Inside Savebox hfill: \hfill XXX}%
Outside Savebox hfill: \hfill ZZZ\par
\noindent
Some more text \usebox{\MyCachedResults}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: A `\savebox` is typeset at its natural width. You probably want `\unhbox` instead of `\usebox`

Comment: And `\parbox{\linegoal}{}` with the `linegoal` package?

Comment: Are you sure you want a box and not a macro?

Comment: @egreg: Hmmm, perhaps you are right in that I should use a macro - sure would simplify things. I was using a `\savebox` for performance reasons as the text may be used several times.

Answer (score 5):

An option using a `\parbox` of width given by `linegoal` from the [`linegoal`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/linegoal) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{linegoal}

\newsavebox{\MyCachedResults}

% The following are from
%    http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91548/bump-right-aligned-text-to-next-line-iff-no-room

\newcommand*{\BumpCarlisle}[1]{% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91556/4301
    {\rightskip\fill\parfillskip-\rightskip
    \linepenalty100
    \exhyphenpenalty0
    \linebreak[0] % <-- Need space here
    %Space before \hspace* allows for a break before it
    \hspace*{\fill}#1}%
}

\newcommand*{\FillLineEgreg}[1]{% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91564/4301
    {%
        \nobreak\hfill\penalty50\hskip1em\null\nobreak
        \hfill#1%
        \parfillskip=0pt \finalhyphendemerits=0 \par%
     }%
}


\newcommand{\signed}[1]{%http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91563/4301
    {%
        \leavevmode\unskip\nobreak\hfil\penalty50\hskip2em
        \hbox{}\nobreak\hfil#1%
        \parfillskip=0pt \finalhyphendemerits=0 \endgraf%
    }%
}

\newcommand*{\FillLineTohecz}[1]{%
    \raggedright
    \parfillskip-\rightskip
    \looseness=-1 % <-- Need space here
    %Space before \hspace* allows for a break before it
    \hspace*{0pt plus 1fil}%
    #1% 
}

\begin{document}

\bigskip\noindent
\savebox{\MyCachedResults}{\parbox[t]{\linegoal}{Inside Savebox Carlisle: \BumpCarlisle{XXX}}}%
Outside Savebox Carlisle: \BumpCarlisle{ZZZ}\par
\noindent
Text \usebox{\MyCachedResults}%

\bigskip\noindent
\savebox{\MyCachedResults}{\parbox[t]{\linegoal}{Inside Savebox egreg: \FillLineEgreg{XXX}}}%
Outside Savebox egreg: \FillLineEgreg{ZZZ}\par
\noindent
Some Text \usebox{\MyCachedResults}%

\bigskip\noindent
\savebox{\MyCachedResults}{\parbox[t]{\linegoal}{Inside Savebox Seamus: \signed{XXX}}}%
Outside Savebox Seamus: \signed{ZZZ}\par
\noindent
A bit of text \usebox{\MyCachedResults}%

\bigskip\noindent
\savebox{\MyCachedResults}{\parbox[t]{\linegoal}{Inside Savebox tohecz: \FillLineTohecz{XXX}}}%
Outside Savebox tohecz: \FillLineTohecz{ZZZ}\par
\noindent
Text before the bump \usebox{\MyCachedResults}%

\bigskip\noindent
\savebox{\MyCachedResults}{\parbox[t]{\linegoal}{Inside Savebox hfill: \hfill XXX}}%
Outside Savebox hfill: \hfill ZZZ\par
\noindent
Some more text \usebox{\MyCachedResults}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @cfr No, this will also work with latex and xelatex.

Comment: So it does. So what does it mean that `linegoal` depends on the '\pdf­save­pos prim­i­tive of pdf­tex'?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newsavebox{\MyCachedResults}

% The following are from
%    http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91548/bump-right-aligned-text-to-next-line-iff-no-room

\newcommand*{\BumpCarlisle}[1]{% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91556/4301
    {\rightskip\fill\parfillskip-\rightskip
    \linepenalty100
    \exhyphenpenalty0
    \linebreak[0] % <-- Need space here
    %Space before \hspace* allows for a break before it
    \hspace*{\fill}#1}%
}


\begin{document}

\bigskip\noindent
\savebox{\MyCachedResults}{Inside Savebox Carlisle: \BumpCarlisle{XXX}}%
Outside Savebox Carlisle: \BumpCarlisle{ZZZ}\par
\noindent
Text \unhbox\MyCachedResults

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does `\unhbox` preserve penalties?

Comment: @egreg You shouldn't ask trick questions:-) `\unhbox` preserves all penalties that are in the box but the savebox (setbox) in an unfortunate premature optimisation when building the inner horizontal list _doesn't_ add penalties and language nodes that would be added to an outer horizontal list in what latex calls par mode.