# Line with a \hbox is overflowing right margin, why?

Tags: spacing, formatting, plain-tex

Let's say I have a `hbox` inside a paragraph like this:

`Do you like me? \hfill\hbox{\quad$\bigcirc$ Yes\quad$\bigcirc$ No}`.

If the text of the question is longer than this "Do you like me?", the line just won't break. The `hbox` with answers will just owerflow the right margin.

Why is that? Is that because I haven't adjusted the penalties? From what I read, for TeX `hbox` is something that cannot be broken into more lines. But why wouldn't it put a line break between the question and the answers?

Comment: Sorry, I meant "hbox".

Comment: this might be helpful: [Bump right-aligned text to next line iff no room](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91548/579)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The breakpoint is *before* the glue, and if it broke there, the first line would be too underfull. You can add an additional breakpoint after the glue:

[image]

```
\hsize 5cm

\hrule

Do you like me? \hfill\hbox{\quad$\bigcirc$ Yes\quad$\bigcirc$ No}.



Do you like me?\ \hfill\allowbreak\hbox{\quad$\bigcirc$ Yes\quad$\bigcirc$ No}.

Do you like me?\ \hfill\allowbreak\hbox{}\nobreak\hfill\hbox{\quad$\bigcirc$ Yes\quad$\bigcirc$ No}.

\bye
```

Comment: Thank you very much. By trial and error, I achieved the same by adding \-. (Is it the same?) Now I am wondering how to make the second line align to the right; using \hfill before the \hbox leads nowhere, I assume TeX eats \hspace after a linebreak?

Comment: @David simplest is probably to put `\hbox{}\hfill` after the penalty. `\-` will at a hyphen if it breaks at that point, so is not the same.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this doesn't work for me. Adding `\hbox{x}\hfill` after the `\allowbreak` makes the "x" stay on the same line the question is. How is that possible if the line is broken *before* the `hbox{x}`? Hope you don't mind me asking!

Comment: @David that's because I told you the wrong thing, will update  answer in a sec