# Line break after \hfill

Tags: horizontal-alignment, line-breaking

I hope this question is not a trivial one, but I was not able to find any answer to that.

I found out that sometimes when I put an `\hfill` command in order to align some text to the right, there is a line break after the first word of the right-aligned text, even though there is surely enough space from the text on the left.

After playing with it a bit, it seems to me that it happens after there was a line break within a word in the paragraph.

I can't see any reason for that, but yet again I might not have a full understanding of how line breaking and `\hfill` work.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

If there is a line break within a word as a result of some verymuchsuperlongword, 
then the text after hfill breaks: \hfill Some words.

If there isn't a line break within a word as a result of some very much super long word, 
then everything looks fine: \hfill  Some words.

\end{document}
```

And that's how it looks:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea what might be the problem and how I can avoid it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Indeed, the issue is due to the hyphen, because TeX will prefer a paragraph where the last but one line is not hyphenated. The `\hfill` makes it possible. Is the `\hfill` used for setting an author attribution? If you type `\hfill Some~words.` then there will be no additional line. However, the `\hfill` could fail to push the words at the end of the line, if it comes too near the right margin.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91548/bump-right-aligned-text-to-next-line-iff-no-room

Comment: Thanks egreg! In my case using `\hfill some~words` wouldn't help since what I actually want to put there is a citation. 
What does work is the solution in the link you've posted, that is: adding `\linepenalty100\exhyphenpenalty0` before.
Thanks a lot again!

Comment: Can we close this as a duplicate, then? Don't worry about this, it's common for newcomers who can't be at ease with the search functions of the site. I could remember the question because I added a clue to my answer.

Comment: Sure. I guess this isn't something I can do, being a newcomer.