# \hfill inside a list does not work properly. What's going on?

Tags: spacing, lists

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \begin{enumerate}
    \item 
        \begin{enumerate}
         \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt \hfill [Lorem ipsum]
         \item I'm going to relate a time-traveling joke, but you didn't appreciate it. \hfill [Lorem ipsum]
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

gives the following output:

[image]

Why is the second [Lorem ipsum] split up even though the item has less wording?

Comment: You have an extra `\item` in your document before the `enumerate` environment. Is this intended to be embedded?

Comment: Related/duplicate: [\hfill after linebreak](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/16330)

Comment: Agreed it's close to being a duplicate, but I thought it had something to do with the enumerate environment so that's what I was searching for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the misplaced first `\item`, it works as expected for me.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt \hfill [Lorem ipsum]
        \item I'm going to relate a time-traveling joke, but you didn't appreciate it. \hfill [Lorem ipsum]
      \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

---

**EDIT** If a higher nesting is intended, I cite egreg's [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/198248/37806):

> [...] TeX will prefer a paragraph where the last but one line is not hyphenated. The \hfill makes it possible.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item
        \begin{enumerate}
          \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt \hfill [Lorem ipsum]
          \item I'm going to relate a time-traveling joke, but you didn't appreciate it. \hfill [Lorem~ipsum]
        \end{enumerate}
      \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Alternatively have a look at `\linepenalty`.

Comment: Yes, but if you embed the list in another list it shows the output in the OP's image.

Comment: Sorry about that. I meant to have another enumerate list, which I edited in now. I put the \documentclass later in case the 12pt mattered, but I forgot to put in the other enumerate environment. Like you said, it is not misplaced but needed for the 'error' to occur.

Comment: The problem is with the hyphenation. Changing the wording just slightly solves the problem. The \linepenalty is also great.

Answer (score 1):

From the explanation by @Ulrike Fischer---        https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16333/197451

Output **with** `\newcommand\quelle`

[image]

Output **without** `\newcommand\quelle`
[image]

Also, the first`\item` should be giving you an error since the `enumerate` environment has not `\begin`--probably you have edited out the first `item` before capturing your screenshot of the output--is that right?

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
    \begin{document}
      \newcommand\quelle[1]{{%
      \unskip\nobreak\hfil\penalty50
      \hskip2em\hbox{}\nobreak\hfil\textbf{#1}%
      \parfillskip=0pt \finalhyphendemerits=0 \par}}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item fg \hfill [lorem ipsum]
            \begin{enumerate}
             \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed 
              \quelle {[Lorem ipsum]}
             \item I'm going to relate a time-traveling joke, but you didn't 
             appreciate 
             it. \hfill [Lorem ipsum]
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{document}
```