# pushing contents against the right margin, if there is space

Tags: spacing

I'd like `\mycomment` in the document below to be such that it `automatically` puts its argument against the right margin on the current line if it fits and otherwise against the right margin on the next line.

How do I do this?

```
\documentclass{article}


\newcommand{\mycomment}[1]{\hfill\emph{#1}}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=2in]{geometry}


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
 \item Hello, how are you today? \mycomment{alright!}
 \item yayayayayya 4kwerjejffkler ejjkerjgejkrnnjrnejkn ekwjewjrwwejk \mycomment{this does not fit on the same line}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\hspace*{\fill}` not `\hfill`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the solution form [Bump right-aligned text to next line iff no room](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91548/bump-right-aligned-text-to-next-line-iff-no-room)

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\mycomment}[1]{%
    \noindent%
    \raggedright
    {\nobreak\hfill\penalty50\hskip1em\null\nobreak
     \hfill#1%
     \parfillskip=0pt \finalhyphendemerits=0 \par}
}


\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=2in]{geometry}


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
 \item Hello, how are you today? \mycomment{\emph{alright}!}
 \item yayayayayya 4kwerjejffkler ejjkerjgejkrnnjrnejkn ekwjewjrwwejk \mycomment{\emph{this does not fit on the same line}}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```