# How to add some horizontal space unless it is the end of the line?

Tags: spacing

I am looking for a command `\customhspace{}` such that

- `AAA \customhspace{2pt} BBB` is the same as `AAA \hspace{2pt} BBB`: it adds some space between `AAA` and `BBB`.
- `\hfill AAA \customhspace{2pt}` is the same as `\hfill AAA`: in this case, there is no space added after `AAA`.

So, in a way `\customhspace{}` adds space only if we are not at the end of a line, "pushed" by a `\hfill`.

Is it possible to have such a command? If yes, how to do it?

Comment: Related Question: [Bump right-aligned text to next line iff no room](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91548/4301)

Comment: Maybe `\newcommand*\customhspace[1]{\unskip\hskip #1\ignorespaces}`? That way `AAA \customhspace{2pt} BBB` won't be exactly the same as `AAA \hspace{2pt} BBB` though, since the additional ordinary spaces before/after the `\hspace` are removed.

Comment: (Would also work with `\hspace{#1}` instead of `\hskip #1`.)

Comment: Thanks @Circumscribe. I didn't know `\ignorespaces`. Don't hesitate to post an answer. I will review your idea in 4/5 hours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question isn't really about removing spaces at the end of a line, but about removing them at the end of a paragraph.
All skips at the end of a line are already ignored automatically.

A possible solution would be to define `\customhspace` as follows:

```
\newcommand*\customhspace[1]{\unskip\hspace{#1}\ignorespaces}
```

This doesn't quite behave like an ordinary `\hspace` in the middle of a line, however, since it removes a space preceding or following it (which includes ordinary spaces).
Whether this is an advantage or a disadvantage depends on how you intend to use this macro.

### Demonstration:

Here is a little sample document that demonstrates how this works. 
Note that it matters whether an `\hspace{...}` is surrounded by spaces, while it does not for `\customhspace`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*\customhspace[1]{\unskip\hspace{#1}\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}

AAA \hspace{2em} BBB

AAA \hspace{2em}BBB

AAA\hspace{2em} BBB

AAA\hspace{2em}BBB

AAA \customhspace{2em} BBB

\hfill AAA \hspace{2em}

\hfill AAA\hspace{2em}% % <- see explanation below

\hfill AAA\customhspace{2em}

\hfill AAA

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Explanation:

TeX removes the last item in a paragraph if it is glue (a skip/space), but only *one* piece of glue will be removed in this way.
This means that if you have multiple consecutive spaces at the end of a paragraph, all but the last one will still be there.

A paragraph produced by `\hfill AAA \hspace{2pt}`, followed by a newline, actually ends with *three* pieces of glue:

- The explicit space character preceding `\hspace`.
- The `\hspace{2pt}` itself
- The newline also produces a space.

If you remove the preceding space and comment out the newline (see [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/156366)), `\hspace{2pt}` will be the last item in the paragraph and will be removed.
The following paragraph will not have a space at the end:

```
\hfill AAA\hspace{2pt}%
```

You don't want to do this every time, of course.
In the definition for `\customhspace` above, I instead included an `\ignorespaces` to make TeX ignore skips directly following this command, and `\unskip` to remove the preceding space, if there is one.

Comment: Like my answer, this will not act *exactly* like `\hspace` if there are spaces present before or after the invocation of `\customhspace`.  You, of course, have already noted this.

Comment: Yeah, perhaps I should have said that at the start of the answer, rather than hiding behind the explanation :).

Answer (score 3):

This would seem to do it except in one regard which may or may not be of concern to the OP.  Spaces following `\customhspace{}`, if they exist, are gobbled.  And I only mention this exception because the OP, in providing code snippets, had spaces surrounding the invocation of `\customhspace`.  In general, I would not be adding extra spaces around an `\hspace` type command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\customhspace[1]{\@ifnextchar\par{}{\hspace{#1}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    AAA\customhspace{2pt}BBB no extra spaces

    AAA\hspace{2pt}BBB

    \smallskip

    AAA \customhspace{2pt} BBB spaces before/after

    AAA \hspace{2pt} BBB

    \smallskip

    AAA\customhspace{2pt} BBB space after

    AAA\hspace{2pt} BBB

    \smallskip

    AAA \customhspace{2pt}BBB space before

    AAA \hspace{2pt}BBB

    \smallskip

    no space before\hfill AAA\customhspace{2pt} 

    \hfill AAA

    \smallskip

    space before\hfill AAA \customhspace{2pt} 

    \hfill AAA
\end{document}
```

[image]